# How can I change the folder names for Rails assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The default names (`stylesheets`, `javascripts`, and `images`) are bugging me and I'd like to use a different organisation practice.

Which way would be the best to change these and how would I do it?

Comment: Rails uses convention over configuration. Unless you have some very odd case (other than personal preference), I'd advise not going down this path.

Comment: Okay. It's not that crazy. I'm just really bothered by the organisation convention being used.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lives in [the doc here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-assets-path)

```
config.assets.prefix = "/some_other_path"
```